# Fill area above line in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am using dc.js to draw the area chart. I want to fill the area above the line.

The reanderArea(true) function fills the area below the line. How to fill above the line with a different color?

```
                    dc.lineChart(composite)
                    .renderArea(true)
                    .dimension(dim2)
                    .colors('red')
                    .group(grp)
```

Comment: What will the filled area above the line represent and what color should it have? dc.js (and d3-stack under it) can only draw things for which there is data, so I think you'd have to create another stack which adds up to the desired total of everything. For instance if the stacks represent percentages, you could use a fake group to calculate what will bring the total to 100%.

Comment: Another option if it's only about changing the background color of the graph is that on the renderlet event, you add a rect in the g.graph-body and fill it with the color you want.